# JSON-Simple java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Tags: java, json, android-studio, json-simple

I'm trying to get the LAT/LNG values from my json(as Double) seen here:

```
{
    "placeNames": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "lat": "0",
            "lon": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Üsküdar Bağlarbaşı Yolu",
            "lat": "1",
            "lon": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Çamlıca",
            "lat": "3",
            "lon": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

And put markers on location in google maps seen here:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(GetJson(getContext())); //TODO: READ JSON FILE
    JSONArray lang = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("placeNames");
    for (int i = 0; i < lang.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject explrObject = (JSONObject) lang.get(i);
        String PlaceName = (String) explrObject.get("name");
        MarkerOptions marker3 = new MarkerOptions();
        Double LAT = ((Number) explrObject.get("lat")).doubleValue();
        Double LNG = ((Number) explrObject.get("lon")).doubleValue();
        marker3.position(new LatLng(LAT, LNG)).title(PlaceName);
    }
}
```

The problem im getting is the fact that LNG/LAT values seem to be coming in as string even though theyre numbers on my JSON file,Any help is appreciated.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

```
Double LAT = Double.parseDouble(explrObject.getString("lat"));
```

or

```
Double LAT = Double.parseDouble((String) explrObject.get("lat"));
```

Comment: I'm using JSON-Simple so it doesnt have functioıns like getString

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If you try:

        Double LAT = Double.parseDouble((String) explrObject.get("lat"));

?

Answer (score 1):

Following is a valid JSON syntax with `double/ float` values that you can use to construct your json as,

```
{
    "placeNames":[
        {
            "name":"Test",
            "lat":29.470237,
            "lon":107.722125
        }
    ]
}
```

also, you can refer to this [website](http://json.parser.online.fr/) for validating your JSON syntax online in case of any doubts. And also, your above JSON parser logic will work on this JSON data.